# How does Dictionary<T> work with key objects that don't implement Equals and GetHashCode?

Tags: c#

If I place a key object in an Dictionary that doesn't implement Equals and GetHashCode how does the Dictionary ContainsKey work? By checking the references are equal?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The base `Object` class implements [Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.equals.aspx) and [GetHashCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx). All classes inherit from `Object` by default. The dictionary will just use these implementations.

The default implementation of Equals tests object references, which will probably be fine in most cases for your dictionary.

The base implementation of GetHashCode is fairly naive, in fact even the documentation states:

> The default implementation of the GetHashCode  method does not guarantee unique return values for different objects.

So the recommendation is to override it yourself if you intend to use an object as a dictionary or hashtable key.

With regards to how this works. Remember that GetHashCode isn't actually critical for the implementation of a dictionary. hash codes are allowed to clash, that is kind of the point. The hash code is just used to help with locating an object, is it the equality test that will be used to check the object is the correct one in the end. Lets just say for arguments sake that every object just returned a hash code of 1. They would all end up in the same pot in the dictionary, probably in some fairly random order (perhaps inserted order) and it would just fall back to using `Equals` to verify the object identity. It wouldn't be efficient, but it would work fine.

So, if you are looking for efficiency, you should consider overriding GetHashCode, but if it's just going to be a small dictionary and efficiency isn't too important, you'll be fine just to leave it with the default.

[All the usual considerations apply. It's best not override GetHashCode for mutable objects, and make 100% sure that objects that return true for Equals() return the same hash code.]

Comment: @DayOne, how does which bit work? I've added some more info. MS don't provide documentation on how the default GetHashCode works, and they also say that it is subject to change between versions.

Comment: The fact that `GetHashCode` does not return a unique value for different objects is *not* a barrier to using it in a dictionary. The most common key type is probably `string`, and there is clearly no `GetHashCode` function that could map every possible string value onto a unique `uint`.

Comment: @Daniel. I've just added something very similar. Good comment.

Answer (score 0):

It uses the [Object.GetHashCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) implementation, but note that this hash code is *not* an object identity:

> The default implementation of the
>   GetHashCode method does not guarantee
>   unique return values for different
>   objects. Furthermore, the .NET
>   Framework does not guarantee the
>   default implementation of the
>   GetHashCode method, and the value it
>   returns will be the same between
>   different versions of the .NET
>   Framework. Consequently, the default
>   implementation of this method must not
>   be used as a unique object identifier
>   for hashing purposes.

If you want to have your dictionary operate on reference equality, you can use the following comparer when constructing your dictionary:

```
class ReferenceComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        return object.ReferenceEquals(x, y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: This adds no value, System.Object already behaves this way.  Without the class constraint, it behaves *very* poorly on value types.

Comment: Also, you should be careful when implementing your own `GetHashCode()` function. If it generates the hash code based on the contents of the object and those contents are mutable, you may end up losing the dictionary element. That's why you should really prefer to use immutable types for Dictionary keys. This is another excellent piece of advice from Bill Wagners's Effective C# - Item 7: Prefer Immutable Atomic Value Types.